# Google Action Display Name/Invocation name regarding numbers

Tags: actions-on-google

Regarding Google Action Display Name vs Invocation name, we have recently submitted an action which is live. The Name contained numbers, but when entering it in the 'Display Name' on the Google Action console, it said `"Could not reserve your pronunciation '<name>' because: Your Action's display name contains digits or special characters."`

So I entered the number in letters and it went fine and is now live.

The problem now is when I say `"talk to <name>"` Google thinks it should be numbers and it fails to load the action correctly.

Also, I see other actions with numbers in the name, so is this a recent change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reaching out through the [developer support forum](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) directly - they would be able to help you identify any issues on the backend with your Action's invocation.